# SQL Server Express edition - read-only database?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm having a very strange problem with a fresh install I have of SQL Server 2008 Express edition (yeah it's a bit old now, but whatever).  When I connect via SQL Server Management Studio, I can both read and edit data (update or insert), but when I connect via my web application's data access layer, which uses `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to try and update and insert data in tables, no changes occur in the database.  The strange thing is that the code runs as if no error had occurred though; no exceptions are thrown, and my update statement causes `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` to return 1, indicating that supposedly 1 row has been updated.  However, it hasn't.  The application can, however, read data from the database via select statements.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?  I even tried tracing SQL Server using [ExpressProfiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/), and its output seemed to indicate that the update *should* have occurred:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE Match SET TicketsSold=@ticketsSold WHERE MatchId=@matchId',N'@matchId int,@ticketsSold int',@matchId=1,@ticketsSold=1234
go
```

Yet `TicketsSold` stays at the same value (123) it was at before, and does not update to 1234.  Is there some kind of "silent" read-only mode SQL Server 2008 Express could be running in?  I'm baffled as to why the database isn't being updated.

By the way, this is a proper SQL Server database I created in SSMS, not some attached MDF file that resides in the same directory as my web application.  The database is not set to "read-only" in database options, and I'm pretty sure that the user that the web application is logging in as has read/write permission on the MDF file; it is logging in as the same user I am logging in as using SSMS - with integrated Windows security - and I am able to update/insert as that user via SSMS.

Comment: can you give an example of the select statement you use to select the record where `TicketsSold` is still 123?

Comment: It sounds like you have a transaction that isn't being committed.  Is your code creating a SqlTransaction and not calling Commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to shf301 in the comments - I was creating a transaction but forgetting to call `.Commit` before the end of the `using` block.  :-D  I put that in and now it works.